# Nightwatch.js - How to assert a checkbox is NOT checked?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I'm using [nightwatch.js](http://nightwatchjs.org/) to do some end-to-end testing of an application, but having trouble verifying the state of checkboxes.

I'm using `attributeEquals()` to verify that a checkbox is checked:

```js
module.exports = {
  "Checkbox is checked" : function (client) {
    client
      .url(client.launch_url)
      .useCss()
      .waitForElementVisible("body", 1000)
      .verify.attributeEquals('#a_checkbox', 'checked', 'true') // quotes necessary
      .end();
  }
};
```

But I also need to verify that checkboxes are **not checked**.

To do that I've tried using `attributeEquals()` again, with various expectations:

```js
module.exports = {
  "Checkbox is not checked" : function (client) {
    client
      .url(client.launch_url)
      .useCss()
      .waitForElementVisible("body", 1000)
      .verify.attributeEquals('#b_checkbox', 'checked', null)
      .verify.attributeEquals('#b_checkbox', 'checked', 'null')
      .verify.attributeEquals('#b_checkbox', 'checked', 'false')
      .verify.attributeEquals('#b_checkbox', 'checked', false)
      .verify.attributeEquals('#b_checkbox', 'checked', '')
      .end();
  }
};
```

But they all fail with a message stating that the `checked` attribute does not exist:

```
Running:  Checkbox is not checked

✔  Element <body> was visible after 68 milliseconds.
✖  Testing if attribute checked of <#b_checkbox> equals "null". Element does not have a checked attribute.  - expected "null" but got: null
✖  Testing if attribute checked of <#b_checkbox> equals "null". Element does not have a checked attribute.  - expected "null" but got: null
✖  Testing if attribute checked of <#b_checkbox> equals "false". Element does not have a checked attribute.  - expected "false" but got: null
✖  Testing if attribute checked of <#b_checkbox> equals "false". Element does not have a checked attribute.  - expected "false" but got: null
✖  Testing if attribute checked of <#b_checkbox> equals "". Element does not have a checked attribute.  - expected "" but got: null
```

That message is correct, there is no `checked` attribute, but the absence of the attribute means the checkbox is not checked, and therefore I want the test to pass.

How can this be achieved?

I'm using nightwatch v0.5.36 if that's significant.

Comment: Can you provide the html after checking the checkbox?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to assert that the checkbox is **NOT checked**. It's unchecked in the HTML from the server. The HTML from the server looks something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9ya2v1x7/ the significant bit being that there is no `checked` attribute, which is perfectly valid HTML for representing an 'unchecked' state... but nightwatch.js' `attributeEquals()` method is throwing an error, because it can't find an attribute to run the comparison on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try: `browser.expect.element('#b_checkbox').to.not.be.selected;`

Comment: I used this for to.not.be.enabled. Was exactly what I was looking for as assert.attributeEquals("#myel", "disabled", true) threw a total lie of an error.

Comment: Straight from the documentation: Property that checks if an OPTION element, or an INPUT element of type checkbox or radio button is currently selected. http://nightwatchjs.org/api#expect-selected

Answer (score 4):

I did this using the css assertations eg:

```
module.exports = {
  "Checkbox is not checked" : function (client) {
    client
      .url(client.launch_url)
      .useCss()
      .waitForElementVisible("body", 1000)
      .verify.elementPresent('#b_checkbox')
      .verify.elementNotPresent('#b_checkbox:checked')
      .end();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert in Nightwatch.js. But this looks promising.

```
module.exports = {
  tags: ['checkbox'],

  'Demo test select a checkbox' : function (client) {
    client
      .url('your-domain.tld')
      .verify.visible('input[id="your_checkbox"]', 'Checkbox is visible')
      .click('input[id="your_checkbox"]')
      .pause(1000)
      .element('id', 'your_checkbox', function(response) {
        client.assert.ok(response.value.ELEMENT, 'Checkbox response is OK');
        client.elementIdSelected(response.value.ELEMENT, function(result){
          client.verify.ok(result.value, 'Checkbox is selected');
        });
      })
      .end();
  }
};
```

Refer to this  [Page](https://github.com/beatfactor/nightwatch/issues/249)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I wanted to check status of a checkbox. If it was not selected, I wanted my code to select it and if it was already selected, I wanted the code to un-select it. This is how I solved it by following vinoth-s comment and the link he mentioned in his answer:

```
client.element('id', 'elements_css_id', (response) => {
  client.elementIdSelected(response.value.ELEMENT, (result) => {
    if(result.value == true) {
        client.click('elements_css_id');
    };
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try fetching and testing if visible any checkbox that matches your id and is also checked. Im using cucumberjs for this task and page objects so this would work on my project. But i guess nightwatch standalone would do something similar.

```
browser.assert.visible('#b_checkbox:checked');
```

and not checked

```
browser.assert.visible('#b_checkbox:not(:checked)');
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this one:

```
client.expect.element('@your_checkbox_input').to.not.have.attribute('checked');
```

and if you want to check value:

```
client.getAttribute('@your_checkbox_input', 'checked', result => {
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test is fine. I looked at the error and seen a simple issue @
**Testing if attribute checked of <#b_checkbox> equals "null". Element does not have a checked attribute.  - expected "null" but got: null** You are passing `.assert.attributeEquals('#b_checkbox', 'checked', null)` wheres it is expecting `.assert.attributeEquals('#b_checkbox', 'checked', 'null')` with `null` as string `'null'`

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Have you verified this? I'm getting an error for all of the values I listed in the question, including `'null'`. I've updated the question to make this clearer.

Comment: `.assert.attributeEquals('#b_checkbox', 'checked', 'null')`  

above doesn't work. I got  error  

    `Element does not have a disabled attribute.  - expected "null" but got: "null"`

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me as I still get the exact same error message: Element does not have a disabled attribute. - expected "null" but got: "null"

Answer (score 0):

you can use `elementNotPresent` if there is no attribute

instead of using this
`.verify.attributeEquals('#b_checkbox', 'checked', 'null')`

you can use this 
`.assert.elementNotPresent('#b_checkbox[checked]')`

Answer (score 0):

This can be really confusing because a checked element and a not-checked element are like apples and oranges.  I will show the commands then explain...

To check if it is checked...

```
browser.assert.attributeEquals('<element>', 'checked', 'true');
```

To check if it is not checked

```
browser.expect.element('<element>').to.not.be.selected;
```

Why does this not work?

```
browser.assert.attributesEquals('<element>','checked','false')
```

If run the command you will get fail and a result that says

```
 "Element does not have a checked attribute."
```

Go to the console and look at the html tag and compare the code from checked to unchecked.  When the tag is disabled you will get something like...

```
<input ...    checked=checked />
```

When it is not checked, the checked tag disappears.

```
<input .../>
```

The attributeEquals function is looking for the "checked" attribute, which is no longer there when the element is unchecked and thus you get error that the "element does not have a checked attribute".  Since this attribute no longer exists, you can no longer use the function attributeEquals.

Answer (score 0):

When I get stuck on a negative test not working like I want in nightwatch.js, I just negate the positive test myself.  Since verify doesn't cause the test to bail out I use a positive assertion if not true.

Something like this:

```
  "Checkbox is not checked" : function (client) {
    if !(client
      .url(client.launch_url)
      .useCss()
      .waitForElementVisible("body", 1000)
      .verify.attributeEquals('#a_checkbox', 'checked', 'true');){
      browser.expect.element('body').to.not.be.present;
    }
```